# How to get the cartesian product of two DStream in Spark Streaming with Scala?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, cartesian-product, dstream

I have two DStreams. Let `A:DStream[X]` and `B:DStream[Y]`.

I want to get the cartesian product of them, in other words, a new `C:DStream[(X, Y)]`
 containing all the pairs of `X` and `Y` values.

I know there is a `cartesian` function for RDDs. I was only able to find [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764207/cartesian-product-of-two-dstream-in-spark) but it's in Java and so does not answer my question.

Comment: Of course.
`A:DStream[(String, Int)]` is a collection of terms with a computed value, associated to each of them.
`B:DStream[Int]` is the result of `count` function, so it contains only one integer value.
I want to compute something using the integer value from A and the integer value from B.
By getting the cartesian product of A and B, I will obtain a new DStream with the value from B added to each record of A, and I will be able to compute my result with a map.
The order does not matter.
I am a very new user of Spark and Scala, so feel free to advise me any better way if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala equivalent of the linked question's answer (ignoring `Time v3`, which isn't used there) is

```
A.transformWith(B, (rddA: RDD[X], rddB: RDD[Y]) => rddA.cartesian(rddB))
```

or shorter

```
A.transformWith(B, (_: RDD[X]).cartesian(_: RDD[Y]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fits perfectly my expectations.