# How to get the cartesian DStream in Spark Streaming with Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have DStream that contains user model and I want to create user cartesian by python API.

I checked [this post for scala API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433509/how-to-get-the-cartesian-product-of-two-dstream-in-spark-streaming-with-scala).
And I make the next scripts for creating user cartesian.

```
user_cartesian = user_models.transform(lambda user: user.cartesian(user))
```

But, next error happened.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
```

`user_models` is the normal Array DStream containing user instance like `[user1, user2...]` and do not contain the pair(tuple) instance.
I do not know why this eror happened.
If anyone have advice, please tell me.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17756

Comment: Thank you tell me the link. I understand Python Stream API can not use cartesian function. If I need cartesian DStream, I have to use Scala or Java API? You know another way by Python API?